# What are best practices for organizing Google Docs for the enterprise?

Tags: google-drive

My company has 20 people. We all use Google Docs. As I continue to get Docs sent my way, I'm organizing them (via collections), but I realize everyone else is organizing them as well. This is a great feature, but it seems like there is a better way to organize docs so that others can find them and not everyone has to organize them.

Does anyone have suggestions on resources for best practices for organizing Google Docs for the entire organization?

I know I can use collections and share them instead of individual docs.

Answer (score 2):

In our company, we use Google Apps and therefore Google Docs. From my administrative point of view, I can click on the fan called **[Service-Settings]** then on the **[Docs settings]** and on this page I can select [sharing options]. It looks like this:

**Sharing options** 
Outside [Company]

*Select the highest level of sharing that you want to allow for your users:*

- ( ) Users cannot share documents outside [Company]

  [_] Let users receive documents from outside [Company]
- (x) Users can share documents outside [Company]

  [_] Warn users when sharing outside [Company]

**Document visibility**

*Select the default visibility for newly created documents:*

- (x) [Company]

  People at [Company] can find and access.
- (_) People at [Company] with the link

  People at [Company] who have the link can access.
- (_) Private

  Only people explicitly granted permission can access.

Answer (score 1):

Collections in Google Docs are also share-able. So, if you wanted to have a standard way of organizing docs in collections, [an entire collection can be shared](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158074) within your company.

Answer (score 1):

I just took as the main admin for a company of 30 people. One of the most useful organizational techniques I've implemented is utilizing google groups for sharing... You no longer need to share individual files with employees or remove them once they no longer need access. You simply remove or add them to the group. Done.